# How can I monitor use of Chrome Remote Desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, g-suite, google-chrome

I started using Chrome Remote Desktop via https://remotedesktop.google.com/ recently.

I set up remote access to a number of computers in an office I'm supporting.

I'd like to promote it as a good way for others to access computers remotely as needed, but I'm concerned that I won't be able to monitor use effectively for potential abuse.

Does using Chrome Remote Desktop create logs or reports that could be used by a G Suite administrator to monitor use?